# Is there a way to determine if an even permutation $a$ exists such that $a\tau a^{-1}=\sigma$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

I was looking at an old algebra exam, and one of the problems were to determine if there exists a permutation $$a\in A_{10}: a\tau a^{-1}=\sigma$$
where $\sigma=(1\space7)(5\space6\space9)(\space2\space3\space4\space8\space 10),
\tau=(1\space2)(3\space4\space5)(6\space7\space8\space9\space10)$. And I'm not really sure where to start. I have tried taking the sgn function on both sides and moving things around, but this doesn't seem to get me anywhere. Is there a general way of determining wether such an $a$ exists?

Comment: Maybe there is a typo in your question, $\sigma$ is not a product of disjoint cycles.

Comment: If you can find _any_ $a$ that works and it happens to be odd, then look for an odd $b$ such that $b\tau b^{-1}=\tau$ and compose with that.

Comment: If $a$ exists it obeys $a\tau = \sigma a$.

Comment: You do know how conjugation works on an explicitly given cycle, right? $$\sigma(n_1\;n_2\;\ldots\;n_k)\sigma^{-1} = (\sigma(n_1)\;\sigma(n_2)\;\ldots\;\sigma(n_k))$$

Comment: @Troposphere Yes, I am aware of this. But I'm not sure that this solves the problem. I am looking for a general way of showing that such an $a$ exists. If the solution is to find a $b$ like you described, then I would just need the existence of such a $b$ instead.

Comment: @Snildt: It provides a way to write down an $a$ explicitly as soon as you have written down $\sigma$ and $\tau$ as disjoint cycles (which the exercise has already done for you).

Comment: @Snildt When you are working with $A_n$, to my knowledge, there isn't something general which could guarantee that two permutations are conjugate. In $S_n$, it suffices for two permutations to have the same cycle structure (type).

Comment: Can you write down any permutation which sends $\sigma$ to $\tau$? Hint: you need to learn that conjugation by an element of the symmetric group acts by permuting the underlying set. Given two elements of a symmetric group which have the same cycle type there is always an element which conjugates one to the other, and when you understand what is going on, you can just write one down. The delicate matter of whether an even permutation will do it is sometimes easy to determine, as here (it is generally easy to find an even permutation where it exists).

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis The conjugacy classes of $S_n$ split in $A_n$ precisely when the cycle type consists of a product of single cycles of odd length (and a $1-$cycle counts here). So in $A_{10}$ you couldn't guarantee to conjugate one $9-$ cycle to another (type $(1)(9)$) nor type $(3)(7)$ but type $(1)(3)(3)(3)$ you could (if necessary swap two of the $3-$cycles). If you have the wrong cycle-type and find an odd element of $S_n$ which works, then only odd permutations in $S_n$ will work.

Comment: @Troposphere But I would need to find $b$ as well with that property, and I don't see how the existence of an odd $b$ with $b\tau=\tau b$ would follow from just knowing the cycle structure of $\tau$.

Comment: @MarkBennet: I think it must be "when the cycle type consists of a product of cycles of _distinct_ odd lenghts", also given the $(1)(3)(3)(3)$ example later in your comment.

Comment: @Troposphere that is what I meant by "single" but you have got the write word - thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, such an $a$ must exist.  Since $\sigma$ and $\tau$ have the same cycle structure, $\exists b \in S_{10}~(b \tau b^{-1} = \sigma)$.  If $b$ is even, you're done.  If $b$ is odd, then $a=b \circ (1~2)$ is even and $(1~2)$ commutes with $\tau$.  This argument works as long as $\tau$ contains at least one cycle of even length.  A very similar argument also works if $\tau$ contains at least two cycles of the same odd length.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one such even permutation,

$$\sigma =(126489537)$$

You line up the cycles structures, and then it is a question of whether to use $(12)$ or $(21)$, the latter gives an odd cycle.

Comment: The question wasn't about finding a specific permutation, but how one would show that such a permutation exists in general (say if we don't know $\sigma$ and $\tau$ explicitly, but just know that they have the same cycle structure. Sorry if I was being unclear about that.

Comment: I understand, but examining the solution to a specific case helps me to understand the general case.